# ASP.Net duplicating standard tools such as a textbox and label when a button is pressed,

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, label, textbox

Hello I was just wondering is it possible to create a function which will duplicate textboxes and label when a button is pressed.

For example: I have Name and address textboxes and labels

```
Label:Name
Textbox:txtName.Text
Label:Address
Textbox:txtAddress.Text
```

I now want a function that will replicate these controls on the same page when a button is pressed for example:

```
Label:Name
Textbox:txtName.Text
Labe2:Address
Textbox:txtAddress.Text

Button:btnDuplicate

Labe3:Name 2
Textbox:txtName2.Text
Labe4:Address 2
Textbox:txtAddress2.Text
```

Is there anyway of doing this? Its hard to explain which is why google is not my friend on this topic. But this would be neat an example may be.

```
Player 1
Player 2
Player 3
Player 4

Button - Add Additional Players
```

When the button is pressed an additional player is added. Am trying my best to explain it to you, but is it possible in C# and ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your components within a web user control.  When your button is clicked, add a new instance of that control and bind it to your click events.